# how to change the text of a button and keep this change until I click again (using Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button

I have a button with the text "follow" which changes text when clicked and becomes "unfollow". However when I reload the page the text modification does not remain and the button text returns to "follow".

How do I keep the new "unfollow" text after reloading the page?

Note that this is a single page app so I cannot use the `<body onLoad="follow()">` method.

```js
$('#myPosts1').append('<button data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" id="btn1" onClick="follow()" data-theme="b">FOLLOW</button>');

function follow() {
  const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
  btn1.innerHTML = 'UNFOLLOW';
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering, why you are reloading the page, you can just depend your button text based on the action, Eg if you click on follow, based on the response you can change the text, later on page load fetch your posts that have info about follow/unfollow in the response based on load the text of the button by default.

Comment: If this is a single page application I'd strongly suggest you use AJAX to send a request to the server to perform the 'follow' action, and update the state of the DOM based on the response to that request

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar I don't necessarily have to reload the page, but even if I change the page and then return to the button page, the button text returns to "FOLLOW"

Comment: You'd need to save the state to your backend somewhere if you have that. And load the state when you load the page. Where you'll save it is up to you.

Comment: You need to store the state of the follow button somewhere. I would assume there's some server-side action performed when the button is clicked? As such you need to retrieve the state from the server and then change the button based on that when the page loads.

Comment: @JarneKompier how could I do?

Comment: You can use localStorage to store text content of your button

Comment: @Phaki i tried but it didn't work!

Comment: You need a backend side to do that, or you need to store that value in a global that can be acessed at any time.

Comment: First you have to set your localstorage item to the text content of your button. Then when you reload, your first function should be the function that get the text from localStorage and set your button to it.